# DBからデータを取得し、順序性を考慮しながらHttp通信でデータを送付したい。

Tags: java, tomcat

以下の処理を行いたい場合、よいミドルウェア(ライブラリ)、方法等あればご教授ください。

クライアントからのリクエストを受け付けるAPIサーバがあり、
このサーバでDBに対し、送信順を考慮してDBにレコードを書き込んでいます。

例えばデータ種別がA、B、Cで通番で1から順番にふられているとして、
データ種別が異なるものは同時送信可能で、通番は同じデータ種別の中では順番に送信しなければならないとします。
(例 A-1とB-2 は同時送信可能。 A-2 はA-1の送信完了後に送信したい場合)
また、送信NG時に再送なども行う想定です。

こういった処理を行いたい場合、オンラインリクエストを受け付ける仕組みとは切り離してシステムを構築したほうがよいのではと考えています。
(常駐化させて、DBが書き込まれるor新システムに通知して処理を実行。任意のタイミングで再送)

現在のAPIサーバの環境
(バージョンは不明ですが、2013年くらいに構築されたものです。)

OS  　: RHEL
アプリ : Java Servlet (Tomcat上で実行)
DB  　: postgresql

現在のシステム構成からできるだけJavaで構築したいと考えていますが、他に便利なものがあれば検討します。フリーウェアのみの想定です。

ご回答いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 「クライアント→APIサーバ→DB」という既存のシステムが有り、このDBからデータを取り出してどこか別のところにHTTPでPOSTしたい、ということで合っていますか？書いてあることだけであればべた書きで済みそうな話なので回答しにくい内容です。べた書きではどんなところに都合が悪いことがあるのか、なぜミドルウェアを探そうと思ったのか、など背景がわかればまだ回答がつきやすいかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。  
やりたいことはご記載頂いたとおりです。またベタ書きでも実現可能であろうということも見えていました。(DB格納後に、データの整合性を見ながら送信処理の実行。前データがある場合はスリープ処理を入れながらループする等)
このような処理は様々なシステムでも必要なことが多いのではと考え、であれば専用のライブラリ等があるのではと考え質問させて頂きました。

別システムにするというのは、現在のシステムに障害が発生した等でダウンしてしまった場合に別システムのほうが影響を受けずに業務存続できるのではと考えたためです。通知に特化し、自身がダウンした場合も復旧を上手く行えるミドルウェアがあるのではないかとも考えておりました。

Comment: 一ヶ月も前の質問ですけれど、メッセージの順を意識するといったら、キューを使うのが一般的でしょう。どれだけ厳密に処理するかによって高可用性が担保されたActiveMQのようなMQを使うか、そこまでクリティカルでないならRedisみたいなキューを使うかやり方は色々ありますね。

Answer (score 1):

一般的なJavaのWebフレームワークであれば構築できるかと思いますが、まずその選定に悩んでいるようでしたら、情報が多いもの＋1つで完結しているものを選定すると良いかと存じます。

日本語情報が出揃っているのをお望みでしたら、以下がありますので参考までに。

https://osdn.jp/projects/terasoluna/wiki/Server_Framework_for_Java_Web

Springフレームワークベースで、かつデータベースのアクセスまでサポートしています。
参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
質問の部分にコメントを追加させていただきましたが、通知に特化したミドルウェア等があればご教授いただけると幸いです。

私自身がJava案件に携わるのが初めてなため、ご提示頂いたフレームワークについても存じあげておりませんでした。貴重な情報ありがとうございます。勉強いたします。